# Using ediff to view a Github pull request

Tags: ediff

I would like to be able to review Github pull requests as a single ediff
"session" (if that's the right word). However, whenever I use `magit-ediff` from
Magit, I can only ediff a single file at once, then I have to exit the ediff
session and restart a new ediff session on the next file.

Is there a way I can use ediff to review an entire Github pull request that may
have multiple commits and multiple changed files?

Comment: You might want to try: https://github.com/sigma/magit-gh-pulls I have not used it, but it may do what you need. Also you might find this relevant: http://endlessparentheses.com/merging-github-pull-requests-from-emacs.html

Comment: You might also be interested in the [second post](http://endlessparentheses.com/automatically-configure-magit-to-access-github-prs.html) of that series that @xmonk linked.

Comment: I have checked out magit-gh-pulls, but I was unable to get it working (it just never shows any pull requests). However, I still don't think it allows me to view a PR as a single ediff session though :(

Answer (score 2):

You can view a Github pull request as a regular patch by appending `.patch` to the pull request's URL.  For example, a pull request with URL https://github.com/bli25wisc/RSEM/pull/6 (modifying four files with three commits) can be viewed as a regular patch by visiting https://github.com/bli25wisc/RSEM/pull/6.patch which is automatically redirected to https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/bli25wisc/RSEM/pull/6

The patch can be viewed in `diff-mode` or you can apply it and compare the differences with `ediff-patch-file`.

Comment: When I use `ediff-patch-file`, it unfortunately cannot resolve any of the files, I get: Ediff has inferred that
 /Users/hinmanm/src/elasticsearch/TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java are two possible targets for this patch.  However, these files do not exist.

Comment: Do these files exist?  Or are they supposed to be created by the patch?  I guess it would be helpful to see the patch in question.

Comment: Here is the example pull request: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10624